# Powerpoint bullet list master slide text justification

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I am customizing a bulleted list in the master slide view on my powerpoint presentation. I would like to have one paricular bullet style 200% the size of my text:

[image]

Unfortunately when I do this, the bullet appears slightly above the text (this is the bullet for "Click to edit Master Text Styles" :[image]

....Infuriating.... How do I get the bullet to align perfectly with the text like it ought to?

Comment: If the size of the text is different from the bullets size it is difficult to align it

Comment: Well then whats the point of having an option for increasing the bullet size relative to the text?

Comment: An idea: If you want a bigger bullet point you can go to **Bullets and Numbering...** and at `Customize` choose the bigger bullet symbol from the list. (It's at General Punctuation subset)

Comment: One (tedious) trick to get around this problem is to create an image that gives you the bullet size you want for that particular size text and that includes space at bottom/top to account for the offset you want from the text's baseline; save as PNG with transparent background, use as a custom bullet.  You have to want it bad ...

Answer (score 0):

For such a case, I would use a text box, put the bullet in it (you may need to add a space to make the bullet appear) or use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (7 from the NumPad which makes `•`), and align the box to the left of the text.

As an example, I used *48 units* for the bullet and *24 units* for the text and aligned them as stated earlier to get this:

[image]